# Apache NET ftp listFiles works but listFiles(String pathName) does not work

Tags: ftp, spring-integration, apache-commons-net

**Background**

I am working on an application which uses spring-integration to retrieve files via ftp. I was using one of the spring-integration's ftp inbound adapter. However even after my repeated tries, I was not able to get it working. So I started looking though the code and found that under the wraps it uses apache commons net api.

**Question**

Using apache commons net library, I wrote the code locally in the same way and it was not working. Here is the code -

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect("x.x.x.x", 21);
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
client.login("xxx", "xxx");
FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles("/AMNH");
```

This returns me 0 rows. This is how the spring-integration executes the call - client.listFiles("/AMNH"). So the list of files returned is 0 and even though I have files at the ftp location, the whole application sits idle.

However, If I run the following code, I am able to retrieve the files. I was wondering what is wrong with the method listFiles when we pass parameters and how do we work around it ? I say this because I don't have the luxury of not executing listFiles(String pathName)

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect("x.x.x.x", 21);
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
client.login("xxx", "xxx");
client.changeWorkingDirectory("/AMNH");
FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles("");
```

Comment: Show us a log files for both scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look into [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway) regarding `changeWorkingDirectory`. You only need to extend the `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` and implement `postProcessClientAfterConnect()` callback.

Comment: Isn't remoteDirectory property there for the same purpose? I can extend. But is there a need?

Comment: It seems remoteDirectory is deprecated since 4.3. aah.. lot of time wasted! Thanks a lot..

Comment: The problem here isn't about a remote directory property, but in the fact that your FTP doesn't allow to list files not from the root of working directory